# Extend db model in Yii2, 2 tables 2 models

Tags: yii2

What is the best way to have a base table and model with an extended child table and model?
So for example you have a menuItems table and another table sandwiches, there is a relationship between the tables of one to one menuItems.id =  sandwiches.sandwichid. So a sandwiche is a menuItem and thus has shared base fields but has it;s own unique field items to.

I would really like to extend menuItems with a sandwich and then access it's properties, make a new scenario etc. So when I make a new sandwich and save it creates the menuitem.

Is this the best why of doing this is there a better way and if not how do i go about this?

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2, I would approach this in the following way:

1. Create the `menuItems` table and a `MenuItems` model that extends `yii\db\ActiveRecord`.
2. Create a separate `sandwiches` table and a separate `Sandwiches` model that extends `yii\db\ActiveRecord`.
3. Declare relationship methods between the two (see [the docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)).

   ```
   class MenuItem extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
   {

       public function getSandwich()
       {
           return $this->hasOne(Sandwich::className, ['sandwichid' => 'id']);
       }

   }

   class Sandwich extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
   {

       public function getMenuItem()
       {
           return $this->hasOne(MenuItem::className(), ['id' => 'sandwichid']);
       }

   }
   ```
4. Have your controller(s) handle any logic between the two.
5. Optionally, you can use `ActiveRecord`'s `beforeSave` and `afterSave` methods to create/modify other records during the save events ([doc here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave()-detail)).

If you're not familiar with how Yii2 handles relational data, I would highly recommend reading the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data) linked in step 3. It can save you a lot of time and effort, and often speed up your code and queries a bit as well.